# Plotting the KMeans Cluster Centers for every iteration in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I created a dataset with 6 clusters and visualize it with the code below, and find the cluster center points for every iteration, now i want to visualize demonstration of update of the cluster centroids in KMeans algorithm. This demonstration should include first four iterations by generating 2×2-axis figure.
I found the points but i cant plot them, can you please check out my code and by looking that, help me write the algorithm to scatter plot?

Here is my code so far:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
data = make_blobs(n_samples=200, n_features=8, 
                           centers=6, cluster_std=1.8,random_state=101)
data[0].shape
plt.scatter(data[0][:,0],data[0][:,1],c=data[1],cmap='brg')

plt.show()
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

print("First iteration points:")
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=6,random_state=0,max_iter=1)
kmeans.fit(data[0])
centroids=kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
print("Second iteration points:")
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=6,random_state=0,max_iter=2)
kmeans.fit(data[0])
print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
print("Third iteration points:")
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=6,random_state=0,max_iter=3)
kmeans.fit(data[0])
print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
print("Forth iteration points:")
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=6,random_state=0,max_iter=4)
kmeans.fit(data[0])
print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
```

Comment: "can you please check out my code and by looking that, write the algorithm to scatter plot" - I think you should try yourself first. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask someone else to write the code for you. You can find examples in matplotlib documentation (e.g. https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html)

Comment: yes i tried like billion times, my point was not to make you write the code i just need help, my statement was wrong, i changed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `plt.scatter()` and `plt.subplots()` to achieve this as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
data = make_blobs(n_samples=200, n_features=8, 
                           centers=6, cluster_std=1.8,random_state=101)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2,figsize=(10,10))

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
c=d=0
for i in range(4):
    ax[c,d].title.set_text(f"{i+1} iteration points:")
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=6,random_state=0,max_iter=i+1)
    kmeans.fit(data[0])
    centroids=kmeans.cluster_centers_
    ax[c,d].scatter(data[0][:,0],data[0][:,1],c=data[1],cmap='brg')
    ax[c,d].scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1], s=200, c='black')
    d+=1
    if d==2:
        c+=1
        d=0
```

This will produce:
[image]

Comment: first of all, thank you so much for your answer, but i think it is not the correct answer to my question, because when i do that for every iteration it gives exactly the same output. My output should be something like this: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/87131/plotting-the-kmeans-cluster-centers-for-every-iteration-in-python

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check if this is something you want.

Comment: You're getting the same output because the centroids aren't changing after the first iteration for the blobs you've created. You can print and check it.